# Can we use the spark sql function on the each row of the dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can we use the SQL function on each row of the dataframe? 
For example :
If we want to apply the IF inbuilt spark SQL function on the row of dataframe, Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide some code and explain what you did so far?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question little more? The reason is - even if you use the `if` function inside SQL query, it gets applied to every row.

Answer (score 0):

[Spark SQL, Built-in Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html) not including IF but there are ways to do it with conditional operators.
Sample code shows how to map on rdd and apply spark sql conditional operators on each value

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, IntegerType, StructField, BooleanType    

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark").getOrCreate()

data_sample = [[1, "r1", True], [2, "r2", False], [3, "r3", True], [4, "r4", False]]
data_schema = [StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), StructField("row", StringType(), True),
               StructField("con", BooleanType(), True)]
data_frame = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_sample), StructType(data_schema))

result1 = data_frame.rdd.map(lambda r: r[0] > 1 and r[1] == "r2")
result2 = data_frame.rdd.map(lambda r: r[0] >= 1 and r[1] == "r2" and r[2])

print(result1.collect())
print(result2.collect())
```

output

```
 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
 Setting default log level to "WARN".
 To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
 [False, True, False, False]
 [False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Yes, we can do that, but I wanna use different SQL Functions such as to_date, Concat etc.  I wanna use the spark SQL operation on a row instead of the data frame.

Comment: Spark SQL does have `IF`. Read [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#if)